# Boxplots by group for multivariate two-factorial designs using matplotlib + pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

I am analysing a two-factorial (M)ANOVA; the sampling design consists of two categorical variables with two and three levels respectively and a response of dimension 4. Having done all the data parsing in python, I would like to continue plotting the data within python, too. (Rather than switch to R for the plotting.) My code, though, is not only very verbose, but the whole thing looks and feels like a really bad hack, too. My question: What is the pandas-matplotlib-way of producing the following plot? Out of interest: I would also be happy to see a solution that is not using seaborn.

The solution in R (the plotting is 2 lines of code):

```
 # Data managment
 library(reshape2)

 # Plotting
 library(ggplot2)

 # Creating sample data
 set.seed(12345)
 dat = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(42*4, mean=c(10,3,5,1)), ncol=4, byrow=T))
 names(dat) = c('Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End')
 gen = factor(sample(2, size=42, replace=T), labels=c('WT', 'HET'))
 env = factor(sample(3, size=42, replace=T), labels=c('heavySmoker', 'casualSmoker', 'nonSmoker'))
 dat$genotype = gen
 dat$environment = env

 # Plotting the data
 dam = melt(dat, measure.vars=c('Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End'))
 p = ggplot(dam, aes(genotype, value, fill=environment)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=1)
 ggsave('boxplot-r.png', plot=p)
```

This will produce the following plot:

[image]

My current solution in python:

```
 # Numerics
 import numpy as np
 from numpy.random import randint

 # Data managment
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame
 from pandas import Series

 # Plotting
 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
 import seaborn as sns

 # Creating sample data
 np.random.seed(12345)
 index = pd.Index(np.arange(42))
 frame = DataFrame(np.random.randn(42,4) + np.array([10,3,5,1]), columns=['Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End'], index=index)
 genotype = Series(['WT', 'HET'], name='genotype', dtype='category')
 environment = Series(['heavySmoker', 'casualSmoker', 'nonSmoker'], name='environment', dtype='category')
 gen = genotype[np.random.randint(2, size=42)]
 env = environment[np.random.randint(3, size=42)]
 gen.index = frame.index
 env.index = frame.index
 frame['genotype'] = gen
 frame['environment'] = env

 # Plotting the data
 response = ['Base', 'State23', 'State42', 'End']
 fig, ax = pt.subplots(1, len(response), sharex=True, sharey=True)
 for i, r in enumerate(response):
     sns.boxplot(data=frame, x='genotype', y=r, hue='environment', ax=ax[i])
     ax[i].set_ylabel('')
     ax[i].set_title(r)

 fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
 fig.savefig('boxplot-python.png')
```

This will produce the following plot:
[image]

As you probably agree, the code is not only verbose, but it also does not really do what I want. For example, I have no idea how to remove the multiple appearance of the legend, and the labelling on the x-axis is odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited** to use `factorplot` instead of `Facetgrid` as suggested by mwaskom in the comments.

If you [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt) the dataframe, then you can take advantage of Seaborn's [`factorplot`](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html):

```
df = pd.melt(frame, id_vars=['genotype', 'environment'])

sns.factorplot(data=df, x='genotype', y='value', 
               hue='environment', col='variable', 
               kind='box', legend=True)
```

You can rename "value" and "variable" as you wish in the melt function.

Here is the resulting chart:

[image: multivariate boxplot]

---

Previous answer with `FacetGrid`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="variable", size=4, aspect=.7)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "genotype", "value", "environment").add_legend(title="environment")
```

Comment: Easier and better to use `factorplot`.

Comment: So much better than my solution.. The legend appears at an odd place, though, in the middle of the last facet, overlapping with the boxplots, so you can read nothing, and in tiny script, too. I tried: p=factorplot(..., legend_out=True); p.fig.show() but, unfortunately, my wish to draw the legend outside the plot was ignored. Is this the case for you, too? Any idea how to place the legend somewhere else?

Comment: I have included my picture. The legend looks fine, not sure what explains the difference. I'm using IPython 3.4, pandas 0.17.1, and seaborn 0.7.0.

Comment: You could try to play with `size` and `aspect`. The larger the size, the smaller the font (because the large picture is squeezed in). Aspect could help make room for the legend... I used `size=4, aspect=.7`, but even with default values the legend was outside.

Comment: I am using: ipython==4.2.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
matplotlib==1.5.1
pandas==0.18.1
seaborn==0.7.0

Comment: Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 26 2015, 22:03:40), thanks for the help!